# SharePoint REST limitation?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, error

To all SharePoint folks,

Have anyone noticed, when we apply OR operator in REST API filter having more than 5000 List items, it will throw error code 500 even if I return single item.

FYI, All columns are indexed.

For e.g.

```
site/_api/web/list/getbytitle(<list title>)/items?$Select=Title&$filter=Author eq <email> OR Column2 eq <some value>&$top=1
```

Even I checked with Microsoft team and they were surprised and said it's part of core logic.

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try after adding indexes to the columns you are filtering with, if not done already. Plan the query in such a way that all the columns used in it are indexed, and the query results in less than 5000 items (before adding TOP).

Also, if the list has already been filled with data, then you might not be able to create indexes to it, so best way is to create the indexes before adding data to the list.

[image]

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-an-index-to-a-list-or-library-column-f3f00554-b7dc-44d1-a2ed-d477eac463b0

Alternatively, you can use SharePoint search REST API.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is known issue of SharePoint REST APIs.

If the `$filter` query (or first part of filter query) returns more than 5000 items it will throw an error, even when you are using `$top` and returning only one item.

This will not work even if you are indexing the columns. Try reducing the number of items returned by first part of query if possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is the known issue for SharePoint.

Using the indexed column can work with a single condition like

```
?$filter=Id eq SomeNumber&$top=1
```

However using And/Or condition will still cause the Threshold issue.

And for the indexed column single condition filter, it's suggested to use data.d.__next, here is a sample for this (with Id column which is indexed column by default):

```
function GetAllThresholdItems() {
    var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('list name')/items?$select=Id&$top=1000";
 
    // Variable to store the list item values.
    var results = results || [];
    GetRows();
    function GetRows() {
        return $.ajax({
            url: url,
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                results = results.concat(data.d.results);
                // If there's next set of data, "data.d.__next" will contain URL. If not then you’re at the end of the records list and the execution of the code will stop.
                if (data.d.__next) {
                    url = data.d.__next;
                    GetRows();
                }
            },
            error: function (error) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Reference:

[Resolve threshold issue in SharePoint REST API](https://www.codesharepoint.com/sharepoint-tutorial/resolve-threshold-issue-in-sharepoint-rest-api)