# I am getting list view threshold although all the columns involved in the filter and Sort are indexed columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, error, list-view-threshold

I have the Workflow tasks list which contain 42,613 items. and inside a list view i have those filtering and sorting (where all the columns are indexed):

[image]

[image]

[image]

But when we access the list view we got this threshold error:

[image]

Although those columns involved in the filter and sort are indexed as follow:

[image]

And the Item count is set to 50, as follow:

[image]

Any advice on this please? how we can overcome the threshold error?

Comment: Have you set the item limit in your view?

Comment: @CallumCrowley yes it is set to 50 items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with SharePoint list view filters and SharePoint REST APIs filters.

If the filter query (or first part of filter query) returns more than 5000 items it will throw an error.

This will not work even if you are indexing the columns. Try using the filter query where the number of items returned by the *first part of filter query* will be less than 5000.

**Similar thread**: [SharePoint REST limitation?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/289373/sharepoint-rest-limitation/289376#289376)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have more than 5000 items that are newer than 165 days? I believe the filters applied in the query are evaluated in the order you specified them and if your first condition exceeds 5000 items the other conditions will not be evaluated anymore because that would exceed the threshold. Although you only might have a very small number of actual items meeting all criteria. I only encountered this with "equals"-conditions, so the "greater than" and "begins with" conditions might complicate this even further.

Comment: Correct, ordering is the key.